# In Visual Studio, is there a way to specify an object type when doing a regular expression find and replace?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2015, replace, find, find-replace

In Visual Studio, is there a way to specify an object type when doing a regular expression find and replace? I'm trying to do a find and replace in Visual Studio but I only want to do it on objects that are of a specific object type (I want to only do this on strings, and not any other object type).

This is my regex query:

- FIND: `(Me\.(?:(?!.*Exclude).*?)) Is Nothing[^"]`
- REPLACE: `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace($1)`

If this capability isn't built in to Visual Studio, is there an extension or something else I could use to do this with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't specify the type of the object in the regex, since it's looking for a string *pattern* and have no idea of what the string really is.

I would give a shot with ReSharper but I'm not 100% positive that it can do such things.